# Where does "\\?\" path/directory points to?

Tags: windows, batch-file, directory

May not really be batch programming related, but I found in one batch file the following two lines:

```
mkdir "\\?\C:\Windows "
mkdir "\\?\C:\Windows \System32"
```

I do understand that these lines should create directories, but the syntax - the path beginning with `\\?\`, and the whole strings are in quotes `"` because of spaces...? Also these directories on the drive C:\ already exists. This looks like writing to some sort of temp? Can someone please explain to me what these lines ACTUALLY do?

Thanks!

Comment: The first one is required to create a directory with a trailing space, i.e. "Windows " since normally the runtime library would trim that down to just "Windows" before passing it to the kernel. The second one is not required. Trailing spaces and dots are trimmed from only the final component in a path.

Comment: Read the Microsoft article about [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/naming-a-file). That code is most likely from a malware script. The first line is designed to create on drive `C:` a directory `Windows ` __with a space at end__ of directory name. Windows prevents that usually and so the command `mkdir` would fail because of `C:\Windows` exists already on most Windows computers. The ``\\?\`` prefix to a path string tells the Windows APIs to disable all string parsing and to send the string that follows it straight to the file system.

Comment: In the Windows API, "\\?\" and "\\.\" both are the root object directory where junctions to native devices are created. In the native NT API it's "\??\" instead. The "\\?\" version is special cased to bypass normalization in an open/create context, but only if it uses only backlash. If it has at least one forward flash (e.g. "//?/"), then it's effectively the same as normalized "\\.\". This object directory is actually a union directory, with a local directory for the user's logon session that shadows the system global directory.

Comment: This object directory for device junctions exists to provide persistent, well-known names for devices, and to support per-user mapped and subst drives. Often native devices have enumerated, non-persistent names such as "\Device\HarddiskVolume2". Junctions such as "C:" or "Volume{...}" are persistent, registered names (e.g. the Volume GUID name is used to persistently mount a volume in a file-system directory). Or sometimes the alias name provides a classic DOS name such as "NUL" (native "\Device\Null") or "CON" (native "\Device\ConDrv\Console").

Comment: The reason the native directory name "\??\" has this four-character form is as a speed hack in parsing. It's actually referring to a caller's local device directory in "\Sessions\0\DosDevices\<Logon Session ID>", but the Object Manager has this directory cached in the logon session itself and in the process object for the calling process, so it doesn't have to bother with parsing all that every time, and also native callers don't have to bother with constructing that path from the logon session ID. Instead native code just uses "\??\". Or in Windows we use the UNC form, "\\?\" or "\\.\".